# Instance variable with property & synthesize and one without them - ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

You can declare a variable like this.

Case1:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *str;
}

@end
```

Also, if you want to set its property, you can do

Case2:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *str;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;

@end
```

And in the .m,

```
@synthesize str;
```

My understanding with the difference between Case 1 and Case 2 is that synthesized and propertied variables in Case 2 can be accessed from another class when this another class instantiates this class.

What are other differences between Case 1 and 2? Say when these variables are just used only in its .m file. The fact that you are setting 'str' properties probably makes a difference, but how? If you don't set property, how are they going to be released with ARC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are fairly confusing in this case because of the way it is set up.

Also it is using what is now old practises.

The new suggested way of doing this (suggested by Apple) is to do this...

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

@end
```

You no longer need the @synthesize as Xcode (since 4.5) will auto generate these for you.

Doing this sets up the property called `str` and an iVar called `_str`.

You now no longer need to worry about defining multiple ivars and properties etc... Just use the property and that's it done.

An example setter method for the property str would look like this...

```
- (void)setStr:(NSString*)str
{
    _str = str;
}
```

Comment: you still need `@synthesize` if you want to use it without going `self.str`

Comment: So for all instance variables, I better declare its property? I shouldn't declare any instance variable between the squiggly brackets?

Comment: @Fonix no you don't. The synthesize is now "assumed" by the compiler and an ivar with an underscore is set up. Rocky, I only ever use properties now. There is now "correct" way. It is more personal preference. But I find properties are easier to manage in ARC and also to control the way they are retained etc...

Comment: Also, with a property set up this way you can still access the synthesized ivar _str. I'll add a setter method as an example.

Comment: @Fogmeister ive got the latest xcode and when i try use an `@property` without the `@synthesize` it always wants me to replace it with _variable? how do you get it to work

Comment: @Fonix use _variable. The _variable is an ivar set up by synthesize to the property variable. i.e. self.variable is the same thing as _variable except self.variable will use any over-ridden getters or setters.

Comment: oh right, but that is ugly. i still prefer to `@synthesize` :P

Comment: You may think it is ugly but by synthesizing an ivar without an underscore you are just creating confusion (evident in these comments) between the property and the ivar. Besides the underscore is Apple's suggested best practise. No offence, but I'll stick with what Apple suggests over what you suggest. :)

Comment: I see. Thanks. Sorry to sound like such a novice, but you declare a variable .h (str in this case) and you declare its ivar in .m  (_str in this case though it is automatically generated). My understanding is correct, right?

Comment: @Rocky just declare the property in the .h file. That's it. Once that is done you just use self.str in the .m file. It is only if you are over-riding the getter or setter that you need to use _str.

Comment: Ok. But I am still iffy about the instance variables in the squiggly brackets. I know that I can just call properties, but in my project I currently have many instance variables in the squiggly brackets. And since I wanted to call them from another class, I set properties...Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Instance variables defined in 'squiggly' brackets (in the .h file) are still available to other classes. They are still defined publicly. The difference is just how they are made available and what magic the compiler does to make everything work.

Comment: iVar access is still, inherently, the most dangerous form of access, as it's all just variable offsets and dereferences instead of dynamic dispatch.  They're certainly "available", but *useable*, probably not.

Comment: In essence Rocky, you don't have to define anything in any curly brackets. Just use properties. Then in the object use self.str.